# How does intent filter work in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

In android if there are more than two apps which can receive same intent then a dialogue will pop up to ask user to select which app to do the action

for ex : when user click on any link it will pop up the below dialogue [image]

So my question is which app will perform this display of dialogue for asking the user.

It will be appreciated if some one explains how does it work.
 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this dialog is open by operating system. it check the manifest of other apps and search in intent filter for action  that is invoked and those that full fill the need of action shows in the dialog.

basically intent filter specify : which activity can respond to which event or action. If it say action_view then all those activities will open that can respond to view intent filter.

lets see.

[image]

here app 1 say i want action **param_c.** so os search in manifest of other application for action **param_c** and all those app that can respond to **param_c** will showed in dialog and now it will upto user which activity it want to respond.
* if there is only one activity that can respond to it then it will directly opened.no dialog will be showed.

Comment: thanks for ans @wqrahd but my question is there might be some application which keeps track of all application intent filter and pop the dialogue , I want to know which application does all that work

Comment: i guess this dialog is created at runtime by android os . it keeps all the manifest entries for action and then search for that action in those list and show them in dialog.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is which app will perform this display of dialogue for
>   asking the user.

**Answer :** System, based on the manifest files of all the applications. And the dialog your are talking is chooser dialog.

**Explanation :**

When `startActivity()` is called ,the `system` examines all of the installed apps to determine which ones can handle that specific kind of `intent`. If there's only one app that can handle it, that app opens immediately and is given the `intent`. If multiple activities accept the `intent`, the system displays a dialog so the user can pick which app to use.

However, if multiple apps can respond to the intent and the user might want to use a different app each time, it is better to show a `chooser dialog`. The `chooser dialog` asks the user to select which app to use for the action every time (the user cannot select a default app for the action).

**For example,** when your app performs "share" with the `ACTION_SEND` action, users may want to share using a different app depending on their current situation, so you should always use the chooser dialog.

To show the chooser, create an Intent using `createChooser()` and pass it to `startActivity()`. **For example:**

```
// Create intent to show chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
```

This displays a dialog with a list of apps that respond to the intent passed to the `createChooser()` method and uses the supplied text as the dialog title.

For more information refer [Intent-Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)